# Significance of accumulation points in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the significance of accumulation points in complex analysis.

For example, the Identity Theorem, and the Principle of Analytic Continuation, both refer to accumulation points.

I have failed to understand why they are important in these theorems.

Comment: It's important because it's part of the statement of those theorems. For me, your question is like asking what's the importance of continuity in the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Jose, I'm trying to follow Needham's explanation of rigidity and analytic continuity. He doesn't talk about accumulation points. He talks about the Taylor series of an analytic function which is zero along a path, developed at points close enough that the discs of convergence overlap. He then considers the domain away from the path to argue the zero value is maintained in the domain of that analytic function. My question is trying to understand acc points by comparing explanations. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306390/needhams-explanation-of-rigidity-leading-to-analytic-continuity